# Settling time vs T of PWM Signal

Tags: capacitor, pwm, dac, time-constant

I reviewed this article: https://www.edn.com/a-faster-pwm-based-dac/
where it says the settling time of the DAC will be 5*RC (till here we are ok), in which RC=16 T of PWM than if this is true than we need an update rate of 5*16*T =80T so we can convert a digital value correctly.

Does this make any sense because in PWM DAC we have always said that the frequency of PWM=update rate?

Comment: Well, what do you think is incorrect or wrong about the article?

Comment: Well my confusion comes from the fact that we need 80T to settle the value so if a new digital data comes(update rate) than right value won't be settled so the true update rate needs to be 1/80T , just need a confirmation about this

Comment: It depends on the specs/requirements that are on the website. If you want that there is good enough filter to have low enough ripple at the PWM frequency, which you usually want to filter away, then the voltage settles slowly.